# Регулярная отправка email на Python(как цикл)

Tags: python, циклы, email, smtp

Хочу написать функцию, используя SmtpClienе, для регулярной отправки email одному адресату по дате. В прикрепленном коде пока просто даты для проверки, пока нужно доработать цикл.

Написал код, проверил на отправке одного сообщения-успешно, но если делать цикл, то отправляется лишь одно сообщение, а остальные-нет(цикл идет до бесконечности).

В коде можете наглядно увидеть библиотеки, которые я использую. Заранее спасибо за помощь!

```
    import time, datetime
    import smtplib
    from threading import Timer
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
    
    schet = 23

    def send_email():
        addr_from = "отправитель"
        addr_to = "получатель"
        password = "пароль"

        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['From'] = addr_from
        msg['To'] = addr_to
        msg['Subject'] = 'Расчет на февраль'
        body = "отправляю расчеты"
        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

        server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.yandex.ru', 465)
        server.login(addr_from, password)
        server.send_message(msg)
        server.quit()

    while True:
        if schet == 57:
            schet == 23
        if now.day == 4:
            print('увидимся через месяц')
        if now.day == 3 and now.hour == 18 and now.minute == schet:
            y = today.replace(day=today.day, hour=18, minute=now.minute + 1, second=0, microsecond=0)
            delta_t = y - today
            secs = delta_t.seconds + 1
            t = Timer(secs, send_email)
            t.start()
            schet += 2
            print('done<3')
```

Comment: Как вы проверяете? Что ожидаете получить в результате запуска? У вас код устанавливает запуск на одно и то же конкретное время (на 18:23 в день запуска) много раз. Это вы так и задумывали?

Comment: Реализовывать подобное внутри своего скрипта - в принципе плохая идея. Практически в любой операционной системе есть свой скедъюлер - планировщик задач в windows или crontab в *nix. Через них и надо реализовывать  периодический запуск вашего скрипта, от которого будет требоваться только отправить почту.

Comment: Я пытался реализовать это задачу при помощи модуля shedule, но у меня немножечко другая задача: мне нужно чтобы он в определенное число отправлял сообщение на почту, а если это выходной день, то смещал на ближайший рабочий день, а модуль schedule он именно в регулярный день/час/секунду.